# Storing a class method in a vector and calling it

Tags: c++, vector, arduino

I'm trying to create a simple scheduler that classes can use to store and call tasks at a later time. The `addItem()` function stores the function and future time passed to it and `refresh()` (which is run every loop) checks if it's time to run the stored method.

I'm having trouble with both storing methods of different classes because of errors like:

```
cannot convert 'void (foo::bar::*)()' to 'void (*)()'
```

and am also having trouble with calling the functions when I do get it working.

Here is my code:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <vector>
namespace Scheduler {
    struct s_singular {
        void (*function)();
        uint32_t timeDelay;
    };

    std::vector<s_singular> _scheduleVec;

    void addItem(void (*func)(), uint32_t timeDelay) {
        _scheduleVec.push_back({func, millis() + timeDelay});
    }

    void refresh() {
        for (auto i = _scheduleVec.begin(); i != _scheduleVec.end(); i++) {
            auto item = (*i);
            if (item.timeDelay >= millis()) {
                (*item.function)();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

If you're wondering how i'm using vectors in Arduino, I'm using the ArduinoSTL library.

Comment: Pointers-to-member are necessarily not interchangeable; you need a polymorphic solution. Can you store `std::function<void()> function;` in `s_singular` instead? Then you can `std::bind` the member function.

Comment: for some reason when I try and use anything std:function it says `error: 'function' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
 std::function<void()> function;` even when I include the functional class

Comment: Make sure you `#include <functional>`. If the error doesn't go away, your standard library implementation doesn't have `std::function` and you'll have to hand-code a polymorphic wrapper. Do you have access to C++11 at least?

Comment: If you have access to C++11 (and therefore variadic templates) and your standard library provides `std::unique_ptr` then you could do [something like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f2d0bb48120dca4d) which mimics just enough of `std::function` to get by.